# Having trouble running a cron job in Unix which generates a dynamic filename for an output data dump

Tags: unix, scheduled-tasks, cron, mysqldump

I am trying to schedule a MySQL database dump by using cron but I get an error for some code that I know works when I call directly in Shell.

Here is the code that works perfectly well in Shell:

```
mysqldump -uUSER -pPASS DB > "/path/to/backup/backup_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`.sql"
```

However when I set a cron job up it comes back with the following error:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Cheers, Ian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
mysqldump -uUSER -pPASS DB > /path/to/backup/backup_`date +"\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S"`.sql
```

an easier solution in the future would be to place your command which works in bash, into a shell script, then run the shell script from cron. If it works in bash, it will work in a shell script.

Comment: Forgot to escape again didn't I! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Common mistake. Any time :)